# need to display dynamic controls in a First row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use the following jquery for create dynamic controls in table.It was working fine but it was show row by row.I need to display all the controls in a single row .How to do this?

```
$("#inputId").click(function () {

                 var table = $('table#mytable');
                 var row = $('<tr></tr>');
                 var col = $('<td style="width:100px;" align="left"></td>');


                 var input = $('<input type="text">');
                 var dropdown = $('<select></select>');

                 row.append(col.clone().append());
                 if( table.find('input:text').length<2)
                     row.append(col.clone().append(input));

                 if (table.find('select').length < 2)
                     row.append(col.clone().append(dropdown));

                 table.append(row);
             });
```

For Live Demo
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZwYD/)

Comment: if possible give us fiddle link

Comment: @PandiyanCool I added Fiddle..

Comment: If you want a single row then create it in the `table` with `html` in first place then append columns into it. **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cZwYD/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are appending a new tr so just append a td

check out following sample

http://jsfiddle.net/cZwYD/4/

```
$("#inputId").click(function () {

             var table = $('table#mytable');
             var row=$('#mytable tr');
             var col = $('<td style="width:100px;" align="left"></td>');


             var input = $('<input type="text">');
             var dropdown = $('<select></select>');


             row.append(col.clone().append());
             if( table.find('input:text').length<2)
                 row.append(col.clone().append(input));

             if (table.find('select').length < 2)
                 row.append(col.clone().append(dropdown));



             table.append(row);
         });
```